# Centring an icon between text and another icon

Tags: html, css, flexbox, icons, centering

I'm trying to get an icon (the play arrow with the ring around it) in the centre of the screen, in between the title ('Random Episodes') and the other icon (the monitor with the + in it).

I have tried too many combinations to remember, let alone list here. If you look at the code snippet below, which is just the header section of the page, you can see what I mean. (The upside down 'T' is just there to mark the centre.) If you remove the `/* */` in the `#add_show_icon` tag in the style section you will see what I want it to look like (as long as your screen size is greater than 590px).
Unfortunately, as you can see, the method I used to get it to look right was to, basically, just increase the width of the icon to match the width of the title (246.3px); this is obviously not a good final solution.

Any help with this would be appreciated as, although it is just for a personal project, I'm hopping it might be a good portfolio/'example of my work' type of project (after a bit... ok, a lot, of tidying up).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>header test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <h1>Random Episodes</h1>
    <div class="completely_random_outer" onclick="open_random_show_and_episode()">
      <i class="material-icons button_icons ">autorenew</i>
      <i class="material-icons button_icons play_icon">play_arrow</i>
    </div>
    <i id="add_show_icon" class="material-icons button_icons" >add_to_queue</i>
  </header>
  <div id=center_marker>T</div>
</body>

<style>
   :root {
    --all-shows-bg-color: #444
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  #header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .completely_random_outer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .completely_random_outer .play_icon {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 250%;
  }
  
  .completely_random_outer .button_icons {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  #add_show_icon {
    opacity: 1;
    /*
    width: 246.3px; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: flex-end; 
    */
  }
  
  .button_icons {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 470%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  #center_marker {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-family: monospace;
    transform: scale(-1);
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Edit for clarification:
I have tried using `justify-content: space-between;` The problem with is is that it just equalizes the space between the elements, end to end. As the text is wider then the icon on the other side, it pushes the center icon over a bit, and thus of center for the page as a whole.

[problem, center icon is off-center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RngTv.png)

[desired look, having to bodge it by increasing the width of the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGr9o.png)

SOLVED! by @Timor-Kodal
[Finished look! Thanks for the help Timor!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ImJL.png)

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="child"> 
            <h1>Random Episodes</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <div class="completely_random_outer" onclick="open_random_show_and_episode()">
                <i class="material-icons button_icons ">autorenew</i>
                <i class="material-icons button_icons play_icon">play_arrow</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <i id="add_show_icon" class="material-icons button_icons" >
                add_to_queue
            </i>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
    #container {
        display: flex;
    }
    .child {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .child:first-child > h1 { 
        margin-right: auto; 
    }

    .child:last-child  > i { 
        margin-left: auto;  
    }
```

Comment: Ok, looks like you can't edit the snippet in browser once it's posted. Good too know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child:first-child > span { margin-right: auto; }

.child:last-child  > span { margin-left: auto;  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="child"><span>short</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>centered content</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>a very very long text section on the right side </span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES! that's it! Brilliant, thank you! Its also an interesting way, I wasn't aware of that flex numbering thing, or at least not aware of it's application. Thank you for you help, especially as I only asked an hour ago and have already got it sorted! I'm going to have to use stack more often! :)

Comment: You are very welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `display:flex` like this:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        center
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Timor. unfortunately, I have tried something like this before, and I just tried it again and it doesn't work. The problem is that `justify-content: space-between;` just equalizes the space between the elements, end to end. As the text is wider then the icon on the other side, it pushes the center icon over a bit, and thus of center for the page as a whole. I would post a picture, but I don't think I can in a comment unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried to add fixed widths to the divs in combination with `justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: sort of, I gave the right hand icon a width matching the text, which did work, but I'd rather not have fixed widths where possible, as I would like it to be as dynamic as it can and, at some point, work on mobile.  I've added some pictures to the post which might help show what I mean.

Comment: Please see my other answer. I have kept this unedited since this solution might be ok for some viewers, because it is short and comes without pseudo-elements